# Words tagged with \index{} appear in the index but disappear from the document

Tags: koma-script, makeindex

I'm typesetting a book using Koma's scrbook class. I'm using PDFLaTex with TexStudio and TexLive on a Windows 10 PC. I'm quite new to LaTeX and first time posting in this forum.

[image: Index image]To make an index I started using the 'Index' package which worked fine. But then I needed to include a a few lines of Chinese characters. The package that I used (CJKutf8) clashed with 'Index'
So I switched to 'Makeidx'.

This works insofar as the words are included in the Index, but they don't appear in the document.
I've included an MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex   
\begin{document}

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \index{\textit{apple}}.  

yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy \index{John}’s 

zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz \index{Aristotelian@Aristotle} zzzz

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The output in the document is in the images.[[image: Document text output][1]]

Can you help me fix this so that the words don't disappear in the main body of text?

Comment: `\index` prints nothing to the text, never has.

Comment: @daleif - reading your comment I just realised I need to repeat the word in the index command. I feel a bit daft.

Comment: we've all been there. IMO it is more flexible this way, especially when you need separate sorting and display versions of the index entry, or subitems. Then it is better to separate them.

Comment: @koleygr - thanks for the edit, how does one post code properly, like you did it?

Comment: @user280391 ... You did it the correct way... but used the wrong quotation marks.... Next time try the original LaTeX left quotation mark (usually next to left `1` of the keyboard) and not the one that comes from the same key of the double quotation mark...